# Material not rendered transparent

Tags: materials, transparency

I have this font object

[image]

According to the material, it should be partially transparent

[image]

But it gets rendered as:

[image]

I tested going 0 % alpha, still the same. What could be wrong in my settings?

Comment: If your material is a Principled BSDF in Blender just adjust the transmission setting to 1.00.If this does not accomplish what you are looking for: If you are using Eevee, scroll down on the material properties page,  set the blend mode to "alpha blend" not "opaque".   If this is the answer I will post it.

Comment: Thanks Goldfish. Alpha blend did not work. Scene file: https://we.tl/t-Aop6CUUVE5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Alpha* of the color itself won't be used (I hope someone will tell how and when it is used). If you want transparency you need to play with the *Alpha* value (a bit below). If you're using Eevee, don't forget to choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* for example, otherwise your object will look opaque:

[image]